# How do I convert from cell array to numerical values in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, type-conversion, cell-array

I want to convert the numeric values inside a string that is stored in a cell array to a numerical array.

Like this:

```
IDcell=cell(10,1);
IDcell(:,1)={'A123'};
IDnum(1:size(IDcell,1),1)=str2num(IDcell{:, 1}(1,2:4));
```

The last part is the problem. What is possible is:

```
IDnum(1,1)=str2num(IDcell{1, 1}(1,2:4));
```

but not the whole array at once.

Thanks a lot,
smaica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers here will work. Matlabbit's use of string will work if you are running a relatively new version of Matlab.  Hielke's loops or use of cellfun  is how I would usually do something like this.  However, here is an alternative purely because there always seems to be multiple ways to solve something in Matlab.

```
>> IDchar = char(IDcell);
>> nums= str2num(IDchar(:,2:4))

nums=

   123
   123
   123
   123
   123
   123
   123
   123
   123
   123
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting in 16b there are new text functions and the string datatype that make this easy

```
>> IDcell=cell(10,1);
>> IDcell(:,1)={'A123'};

>> IDcell = string(IDcell);
>> nums = extractAfter(IDcell,'A');
>> nums = double(nums)

nums =

    123
    123
    123
    123
    123
    123
    123
    123
    123
    123
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a loop:

```
n = size(IDcell,1);
IDnum = zeros(n, 1);
for i in 1:n
    IDnum(i,1) = str2num(IDcell{i, 1}(1, 2:4));
end
```

What you also might find interesting is [cellfun](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html)